# PHP Multithreading - Is it safe

Tags: php, multithreading

[EDITED]

BACKGROUND: I am considering using **pthread** package in a CLI app under linux. I found many heated debates about the status of thread safety and on balance it looks like something to avoid due to the inherent non thread-safe nature of many php functions.

But from  [this docs page](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.obtaining.php): "Thread Safety works by creating a local storage copy in each thread, so that the data won't collide with another thread". This would seem to 'fix' the problem and obsolete much of the old information (even if the actual php code has not been rewritten).

QUESTIONS:

a) Has the current php thread safety model been **demonstrated** to be **not safe** for any reason?

b) There must be speed and memory hits loading the interpreter into every thread -- any statistics available?

PLEASE: No opinions, educated or otherwise, just demonstrable, up-to-date, data.

Comment: Your second question is based on an invalid assumption: Threads generally share a memory space, so the interpreter ist not "loaded into every thread" but rather once into the process. For any possible issues, check the bug-tracking system.

Comment: @Ulrich Do you mean the 'process' of generating threads, or the 'process' being each thread? To use a separate copy of the interpreter for each thread would seem to fix non-thread-safe functions problem. No?

Comment: The term "process" has a specific meaning in computing, check out e.g. the documentation of the process tag here at SO, and it's that meaning which I meant.

Comment: @Ulrich re bug tracker. Good idea. pthreads has a very clean history. Only one open bug which is to do with PDO. It is known that some extensions have issues so that's ok.

Comment: @Ulrich re process. We are definitely talking threading here, not multiprocessing, so the threads are operating under one process. I get that threads use shared memory, processes do not. I also understand that in the past php's problem was that many functions were (and are still) not written to be thread-safe. Lastly, and I may well be wrong, I understand that each thread in php now uses a separate copy (?) of the interpreter so thread safety is not an issue within the interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Full Disclosure:** I'm an internals contributor, and I wrote pthreads.

The first release of PHP with a threading model was on 22nd May 2000, the arrival of PHP4.

There were teething problems, not caused by the theory of model at all, but by code that broke the model; For example, the invocation of non re-entrant functions.

The invocation of non re-entrant functions can still pose a problem; It doesn't matter what model the calling code uses if the callee is going to ignore it, and do something like use globally shared or static state.

In the year 2000, it wasn't so common-place for libraries or functions to be re-entrant by default as it is today. Primarily because non-embedded multi-core systems weren't generally available until later in the naughties.

Nowadays it is common-place for the default version of a library to be re-entrant, or as in the year 2000 provide a re-entrant version.

These teething problems are a distant memory in the year 2015.

PHP is composed of many modules, from the allocator and the executor, to the standard library, and all the extensions that are thin wrappers around third party libraries.

Thread safety is actually achieved by ensuring that each thread has a unique copy of all module globals.

So threads operate in different regions of memory entirely, which is not like a normal multi-threaded application at all.

They can technically share, but they don't: Share Nothing.

> Can the naysayers be finally put to bed?

**Yes**, there is no debate; PHP has a robust, proven, thread safety model.

> There must be speed and memory hits loading the interpreter into every thread -- are they noticeable?

Yes, you can measure it, nothing happens for free.

However, the alternative is to share module globals between threads.

Module globals are extremely high frequency, referenced on allocation, free, print, fetch object, fetch resource, and a million things besides.

If they were shared, you would need to synchronize access to them, introducing huge contention for locks, in addition to an enormous number (somewhere between millions and tens of millions) of additional instructions per request.

The alternative would cripple PHP.

In reality, the cost of a separate interpreter is *just* the cost of initializing separate module globals, and when you consider the alternative, *it is extremely cheap*.

At no time does pthreads break the threading model of PHP, even when it appears to, it cannot.

That's all there is to say about that.

Comment: Are class-static or function-static objects shared? Point is that people still write non-reentrant code: `function getFoo() { static $foo = null; if (!$foo) $foo = allocateFoo(); return $foo; }`. If it's shared, it's not thread-safe. If it's not shared, `Foo` is allocated twice.

Comment: @Joe Thank you so much for chiming in. I believe you already! During many hours of research I found the bad press overwhelmed your other SO entries but the man page clue sparked renewed interest. Hence this quest for ~demonstrable issues~. Anyway, the question has been shut down so we'll never know.  As an aside, more detailed documentation would allow threading newbs like me to more easily filter BS.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt nothing is shared, "Share Nothing" ... All php functions are in effect re-entrant, because any thread that executes a function it did not compile is actually executing a copy of the function. Not just for pthreads, but for anything that caches code: Opcache/APC etc ... This means ```$foo``` is allocated ```n``` times, where ```n``` is the number of threads executing the function, because ```$foo``` from any context cannot be shared ...